# Using Python new line (\n) with ArcGIS geoprocessing progress dialog?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, python-script-tool

I am currently using in my ArcGIS 10.3 toolbox script;

```
# Get the spatial reference
spatialRef = arcpy.Describe(template).spatialReference.name 

#Loop through shapfiles in folder and reproject
for fc in fcList:
fcspatialRef = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference.name
if fcspatialRef != spatialRef:
    arcpy.Project_management(fc, outFolder + "\\" + fc, template) 

# Print shapefile Project results 
arcpy.AddMessage("\n" + fc)

# Return any errors   
except:
arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

Is there a way to seperate these results in the geoprocessing dialog window by a line spacing because it looks cluttered?

```
arcpy.AddMessage("\n" + fc)
```

kind of works but gets;

Running script Project...

abc.shp

xyz.shp

123.shp

How can I make the list like this please?;

![enter image description here][1]

---

Answer (score 5):

I just created a simple Python script tool with no parameters using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop by adding the script below to a toolbox.

```
import arcpy

fc = r"C:\temp\abc.shp"

arcpy.AddMessage(fc + "\n")
arcpy.AddMessage(fc)
arcpy.AddMessage(fc + "\n")
```

When I ran the tool it produced the expected output below:

```
Start Time: Tue Apr 14 18:20:45 2015
Running script Script...
C:\temp\abc.shp

C:\temp\abc.shp
C:\temp\abc.shp

Completed script Script...
Succeeded at Tue Apr 14 18:20:45 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.02 seconds)
```

All looks to be working to me.

Please note that every time you use:

```
arcpy.AddMessage(fc + "\n")
```

you will get the contents of `fc` and then a blank line, while

```
arcpy.AddMessage(fc)
```

will give you only the contents of `fc`, while

```
arcpy.AddMessage("\n")
```

will give you just a blank line, and

```
arcpy.AddMessage("\n" + fc)
```

will give you a blank line and then the contents of `fc`.

I am unclear of the relevance of the code below to your question.

```
arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want the space seperator between the processed fc names than just **do not include the '\n'** in the add message statement:

e.g.

```
if fcspatialRef != spatialRef:
    arcpy.Project_management(fc, outFolder + "\\" + fc, template)
    arcpy.AddMessage('Reprojected...{}'.format(fc))
```

**Result looks like:**

```
Reprojected...abc.shp
Reprojected...xyz.shp
Reprojected...123.shp
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want extra spaces at the beginning of the script running just add additional add message statments before the project code:

e.g.

```
arcpy.AddMessage('\n\n\n') # adds three returns

if fcspatialRef != spatialRef:
        arcpy.Project_management(fc, outFolder + "\\" + fc, template)
        arcpy.AddMessage('Reprojected...{}'.format(fc))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
arcpy.AddMessage(fc + "\r")
```

Comment: Nathan same affect in the loop, line spaces between all shapefiles; outside loop, no affect.

Answer (score 0):

using;

```
arcpy.AddMessage("\n")
```

At start of my script got the line space I needed.