# arcpy.AddMessage does not produce newlines in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, newline

I would like to produce additional newlines when using `arcpy.AddMessage` .  I am using arcpy code assigned to a geoprocessing tool and want to have a newline between some messages. This doesn't happen.

```
import arcpy

line1 = "This is line 1 \n"
line3 = "This is line 3" + "\n"
line6 = "\nThis is line 6"

arcpy.AddMessage(line1)
arcpy.AddMessage(line3)
arcpy.AddMessage(line6)
```

Produces

```
This is line 1
This is line 3
This is line 6
Completed script Script...
```

I've seen the answer to [Using Python new line (\n) with ArcGIS geoprocessing progress dialog?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142508), and the answers there indicate that the above should work.  I note that the OP is using ArcGIS for Desktop. I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This smells like a bug to me. I tried it in ArcGIS Pro 2.4.2 and got the same results. I did, however, manage a workaround. It's not ideal, but if you have some text before and after the `\n`, then the results are as expected.

```
import arcpy

line1 = "This is line 1\n..."
line3 = "This is line 3" + "\n..."
line6 = "Some Text \nThis is line 6"

arcpy.AddMessage(line1)
arcpy.AddMessage(line3)
arcpy.AddMessage(line6)
```

Gave me the following results:

```
This is line 1
...
This is line 3
...
Some Text 
This is line 6
```

Unfortunately, whitespace is ignored. So, if you have the following code with spaces after the `\n` then you get the original results:

```
import arcpy

line1 = "This is line 1\n  "
line3 = "This is line 3" + "\n  "
line6 = "Some Text \nThis is line 6"

arcpy.AddMessage(line1)
arcpy.AddMessage(line3)
arcpy.AddMessage(line6)
```

Gave me the following results:

```
This is line 1
This is line 3
Some Text 
This is line 6
```

Similarly, replacing the space with `\t` also has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried doing this using some Python string formatting and I *think* it may do what you want.  If you put this code behind a Python Script Tool, with no parameters, and Run it:

```
import arcpy

line1 = "This is line 1"
line3 = "This is line 3"
line6 = "This is line 6"

arcpy.AddMessage("{0}{3}{1}{3}{3}{2}".format(line1,line3,line6,"\n"))
```

then I think the output you see will be:

```
Running script Script...
This is line 1
This is line 3

This is line 6
Completed script Script...
```

---

Alternatively, another workaround has been proposed at [arcpy.AddMessage does not produce newlines in ArcGIS Pro](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/arcpy-addmessage-does-not-produce-newlines-in/m-p/92054/highlight/true#M7183) by JoshuaBixby who found that a zero-width space ('\u200B') works when used as a Unicode literal.

```
arcpy.AddMessage(u"\u200B") ‍‍‍
```